# Calculate Local Binary Pattern with radius

Tags: textures, classification, lbph-algorithm

I'm confused with a local binary pattern that uses radius. I have read the journal by Ojala et al, where they use this equation to calculate the center pixel :Eq.1

[image]

Where :Eq.2

[image]

with :

R  = Radius

P  = amount of neighborhood pixel

gp = neighborhood pixel

gc = center pixel

> for example R=2;P=16(from 0-15)
>   if s(g15-gc)=1 and the other is 0
>   so the LBP value is:
>   LBP=1*2^15=32768

so, how this big value turn into pixel value?

Comment: you can see this project for working swift example https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2/tree/master/examples/Mac/FilterShowcase

Answer (score 2):

This is not how LBP works, it calculates the value of neighboring pixels (i.e 0 or 1). Then LBP makes a pattern of it for example 1101101 which is in some binary form. After that it converts the binary value to decimal value. **

**> We will put that value in pixel value as lbp works on gray images so

> it wont matter how big the value is.**

**

For more explaination see the picture below [image] https://slideplayer.com/slide/4512194/15/images/18/LBP(Local+Binary+Pattern).jpg